# Dependency in RCP plugin project java for visibility of view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a plugin project in eclipse(Say p1)

Another plugin(Say p2)

P1 is dependent on p2. So, I added in dependency tab of p1 (added p2)
all the classes of p2 is visible in p1

But I am not able to see the classes of p2

I want view of p1 should visible in view of p2
If you have any solution Let me know.
[Export P2][4]
[Export P1][5]
And here If I will import the p1 plugin, then I am getting Dependency cycle.
I want the class of p1 should be visible to p2 plugin.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGoqA.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPhMg.png`enter code here`

Comment: Did you also import the packages?

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF for both projects and indicate which classes you are trying to use

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of exported plugin.

Comment: Your error log shows a lot of internal errors. Maybe something is not working during compilation and that's why you cannot acccess the class?

Comment: Also (sorry for asking): is your class in p2 declared public?

Comment: Plus, you should remove that /src/treeview entry from the classpath in the runtime tab. That does not belong there. Can you show the Dependencies tab of p1 as well (or paste the MANIFEST.MF source from both plugins as suggested by greg-449)

Comment: Yes p2 is declared as public and I removed the src/treeview also.

Comment: Can you tell me what internal errors??

Comment: Stefan I have attached the both the plugin's manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Did you export the packages from `p2`?

To have a class from `p2` available in the classpath of `p1`, you need to both

- export the package containing the class from `p2` (Manifest editor, Runtime tab, left side), and
- import the package in `p1` (Manifest editor, Dependencies tab, right side) or, alternatively, require the bundle `p2` in `p1` (same tab, left side).

Comment: Yes I diid it. But I am not able to get the class of p1 in p2 plugin project